# Get element of a responseText JSON of an OpenLayers GET request

Tags: javascript, json, gis, openlayers, responsetext

I am trying to use `OpenLayers.Request.GET` to load data from url in JSON format.

Here's the request (note: url works fine, it brings data in JSON format):

```
var request = OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wrspc/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=wrspc:layer1&maxFeatures=60&outputFormat=json",
    callback: handler
});
```

for the handler I tried to get the `request.responseText` and show a specific key in the json file like this:

```
var obj;

function handler(request) {
    obj = request.responseText;
    alert (obj.features[0].indicator);
}
```

and here's my JSON:

```
 {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"titid","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[3694.7863290442,3749.0463695516],[9328.2052648721,3756.61081112875],[3694.18117371807,3861.9059202327],[9340.68659347435,3834.4171230714],[9334.7863290442,3749.0463695516],[3634.7863290442,3839.0463695516]]]]},"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"name1":"asme","number":9130,"indicator":"20","gid":939}}],"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"2684"}}}
```

but I get this error: (note the TestPrint.html:506 is the alert line)

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined TestPrint.html:506
 GeoExt.form.FormPanel.listeners.actioncomplete TestPrint.html:506
 h.Event.fire ext-all.js:21
 h.Observable.fireEvent ext-all.js:21
 (anonymous function) ext-all.js:21
  h.Event.fire ext-all.js:21
  h.Observable.fireEvent ext-all.js:21
  Ext.form.BasicForm.Ext.extend.afterAction ext-all.js:21
  GeoExt.form.SearchAction.Ext.extend.handleResponse SearchAction.js:147
  OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.v1.OpenLayers.Class.handleRead OpenLayers.js:843
  (anonymous function) OpenLayers.js:413
  (anonymous function) OpenLayers.js:62
  OpenLayers.Request.runCallbacks OpenLayers.js:509
  d.onreadystatechange OpenLayers.js:508
  b.dispatchEvent OpenLayers.js:751
  c OpenLayers.js:744
  _object.onreadystatechange OpenLayers.js:748
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't parse your response, the function you need to use is [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
function handler(request) {
    //responseText is the raw JSON string, you need to convert it to a JS object
    //use var keyword to define new variables inside your function scope
    var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    //note that indicator is not a valid features property, you should change it!
    alert(obj.features[0].indicator); //return undefined, change it maybe to .type
}
```

Your error is given by your attempt to access *"all your JSON".features* which is undefined(have you ever heard about a string that has `features` property(it should be a list)? I don't really think so :P

Comment: i parse it but i have this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of undefined ,   i change it to  alert(obj.features[0].type); as you said but still don't recognize feature,  i don't know how to get the value of the indice. and i don't know why is indicator is invalid

Comment: Try this snippet, as you can see it works. You should do this: `alert(typeof request.responseText)` so we can understand if it is a problem of response(but I don't believe, I bet it will display "string")

Comment: i try it it gives me string, but when i try this alert(typeof obj) and obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText); i get UNDEFINED !! So it doesn't success to parse the string to Json !!!

Comment: Do you define `obj` before or after doing the `alert(typeof obj)`?

Comment: before the alert, i did this and it works obj.features[0].properties['indicator']

Comment: It makes no sense, how is it possible that `obj` is *undefined* and you can access features etc?

Comment: Outside the handler? And how can you get `request.responseText` if you are outside the handler? I don't understand what you're telling me °°

Comment: actually it's not that the hole code i do my alert on another action but in the handler i recupere my obj and the use it in another action and it worked with this: obj.features[0].properties['indicator']   not with this :obj.features[0].indicator]   because the indicator is inside the properties if u take a look at my json

Comment: Yes I know, in fact I told you not to use it but to change it to another **valid** property of your json. What are we arguing about?

Answer (score 0):

you can reach your "indicator" object with following way(it is nested under properties feature):

```
obj.features[0].properties['indicator']
```

in such cases you can use [online json parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) for understanding your json structure.

your json:

```
{

    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "id":"titid",
            "geometry":{
                "type":"MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates":[
                    []
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name":"the_geom",
            "properties":{
                "name1":"asme",
                "number":9130,
                "indicator":"20",
                "gid":939
            }
        }
    ],
    "crs":{
        "type":"EPSG",
        "properties":{
            "code":"2684"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i try it but still gives the same error with "cannot read property "features" of undefined" because the the type of obj is undefined, as i said in the comment bellow when i try to do this:  alert(typeof obj) with  obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText); i get UNDEFINED !! So it doesn't success to parse the string to Json !!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, now it works with the `eval` function,

```
obj = eval('(' + request.responseText + ')');
```

and with `alert(obj.features[0].properties['indicator']);`.